# loop: selection of variable for correlation function in r

Tags: r, variables, loops, dataframe

Here is what I intend to do (for a fairly large number of variables and dataset):

```
mygroupdf <- data.frame (varname = c("A", "B", "c1", "D2",
    "E", "F", "g1"), group = c(1, 1, 1, 2,3,3,4))

> mygroupdf
      varname group
  1       A     1
  2       B     1
  3      c1     1
  4      D2     2
  5       E     3
  6       F     3
  7      g1     4
```

This dataframe only consists of information for grouping of variables:

```
group 1 = A, B, c1
group 2 = D2
group 3 = E, F
group 4 = g1
```

Second dataset - contains actual data

```
set.seed(1234)
dataf <- data.frame (yvar = rnorm (10, 10,3), 
    A = sample(c(1,0), 10, T), B = sample(c(1,0), 10, T), 
    c1 = sample (c(1,0), 10, T), D2 = sample (c(1,0), 10, T), 
    E= sample (c(1,0), 10, T),F = sample (c(1,0), T), 
    g1 = sample (c(1,0), 10, T))

# manual workout:
xtemp <- dataf$A* dataf$B * dataf$c1 # all from group 1
# I error in previous version it is * not + 
# (is product of all members of a group i.e. 
 xtemp <- dataf$D2 (- group 2)
 xtemp <- dataf$E * dataf$F (- group 3)
 xtemp <- dataf$G (- group 4)
```

Then correlation of the product with Yvar:

```
x <- cor(dataf$yvar, xtemp)
```

I want to wrap it to a function so that I can apply it to the 1000 groups of variables in my dataset.

```
   corrfun <- function (x, V1, V2, V3) {
           xtemp <- V1 * V2  + V3
           x <- cor(dataf$yvar, xtemp)
           return (x)
          }
```

As different groups have different variables, I am not sure how can I build such a function and apply to whole dataset. Help please !

Edits: process:

[image]

Comment: Not sure I follow when you say different groups have different variables. Since this is a `data.frame`,isn't the dim going to be the same? Are you talking about different variable names?

Comment: @Maiasaura please see my recent edits, actually I had typo it is "*" not "+" while creating xtemp.

Comment: There are two datasets. The problem is the while creating variable xtemp, there might be n number of variables.

Comment: There are only two groups (0,1) right? Each group has the same set of variables (A,B,c1,D2,E,F), right? So why doesn't one function do it all?

Comment: Then are we talking different data.frames? I'm guessing that's what you mean.

Comment: mygroupdf (has information about group of variables) and  dataf has real data to be worked on

Comment: No there are four group of variables (it is not group of subjects, which makes sometime confusing). see my recent edits.

Comment: I give up. Can't follow your example at all.

Comment: sorry, I am trying to update it to make it clear

Comment: @Maiasaura please see my recent figure and expected output elements, if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll wager a guess...

```
corrfun <- function (group.no, x=dataf, x.lookup=mygroupdf) {
  xtemp <- apply(x[x.lookup$varname[x.lookup$group == group.no]], 1, prod)

  out <- cor(x$yvar, xtemp)

  return (out)
}

>     corrfun(1)
[1] 0.35593
> corrfun(2)
[1] 0.4181311
>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and guess (indeed is right guess !!!), can we put in loop instead of typing group.no every time.

Comment: you could or you can use `sapply(unique(mygroupdf$group), corrfun)`

Comment: Your code will fail for one subtile error: with default settings, `mygroupdf$varname` will be a factor, and subsetting a data.frame with a factor will use its numeric value, not its character interpretation. You'll get the correct output format, but wrong numbers.

Comment: @MvG Good point! I have `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` in my `.Rprofile` so I forget about that stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Another answer..

```
cbind(
  group = unique(mygroupdf$group),
  corr = 
    do.call(
      c,
      lapply(
        unique(mygroupdf$group),
        function(x) {
          varnames <- unique(mygroupdf[mygroupdf$group == x, 'varname'])
          products <- apply(as.matrix(dataf[, colnames(dataf) %in% varnames]), 1, prod)
          cor(products, dataf$yvar)
        }
      )
    )
)
```

which gives

```
     group       corr
[1,]     1  0.3559300
[2,]     2  0.4181311
[3,]     3         NA
[4,]     4 -0.1015003
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(unique(mygroupdf$group), function(x) {
  a <- as.character(mygroupdf$varname[mygroupdf$group == x])
  cor(dataf$yvar, apply(dataf[a],1,prod))
})
```

1. **unique:** identify unique group numbers
2. **sapply:** to each of them apply the function
3. **a <- …:** let `a` be the corresponding variable names
4. **dataf[a]:** choose the approproate columns from the data frame
5. **apply(…prod):** compute product for each row
6. **cor:** correlate
7. **sapply:** combine results to a simple vector

Answer (score 0):

And to create yet another answer using my current favorite library:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mygroupdf, .(group), summarise,
      cor=cor(dataf$yvar, apply(dataf[as.character(varname)],1,prod)))
```

This will generate the following result:

```
  group        cor
1     1  0.3559300
2     2  0.4181311
3     3         NA
4     4 -0.1015003
Warning message:
In cor(dataf$yvar, apply(dataf[as.character(varname)], 1, prod)) :
  the standard deviation is zero
```